# How to hide cracks on the joints between wood and plaster?

Tags: drywall, wood, plaster, cracks, tape

I have a plastered brick wall, that ends with a wooden piece that's finished like the plastered wall.  However, there is always a crack at the edge between the wood and the plastered wall.

My question is: how to hide such crack so that it does not come back?

I thought to use drywall's mesh or paper tapes.  However I have no idea how well would this help.

Comment: How about a picture so we can see what you see

Comment: Paintable silicone caulk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have expansion and contraction of two dissimilar materials. The resulting crack is remedied by caulking the joint between the two. As said above paintable silicone is one type. Latex caulk is most common and may work in your instance. For a larger gap or one with extra movement a polyester caulk that stays very flexible such as Vulkem is the answer. If you provide a pic or 2 we can recommend exactly what you need.